# Очистка кэша в тестах django

Tags: django, юнит-тесты

У меня сейчас выполняется очистка кэша перед каждым тестом т.е в каждом тесте прописывается `cache.clean()`, но как мне известно класс `SetUp` выполняется перед каждым тестом, при попытке добавить `cache.clean()` в этот класс получаю ошибку.

```
AttributeError: 'LocMemCache' object has no attribute 'clean'
```

Как исправить данную ошибку, ну или есть ли другой способ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cache` объект не имеет `clean()` метода, но имеет `clear()`

```
cache.clear()
```

Comment: Сорри, невнимательность =(